# Error in java at adding methods

Tags: java

I read that you can add extra methods for an object, or override the abstract methods in this way, yet I have an error. Can you tell me if this is even possible or what I have done wrong?

```
public abstract class Pesti {
    public abstract void ud();
}

public class EX2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pesti p = new Pesti() {
            public void ud() {
                System.out.println("Pestele este ud!");
            }

            public void inn() {
                System.out.println("Innoata!");
            }
        };
        p.ud();
        p.inn();
    }
}
```

It tells me that it cannot find method `inn`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is creating an anonymous sub-class of your `Pesti`. However, since your `p` variable is of type `Pesti`, you can only call methods declared in the `Pesti` class (or any of its super-classes). Therefore you can call `ud()`, but not `inn()`.

If you could cast `p` to the type of the sub-class, you could have called  `inn()`, but since this is an anonymous sub-class instance, you can't cast to that type.

You could declare `inn()` as an abstract (or concrete) method in `Pesti`. Then your code would pass compilation, and the implementation of this method in the anonymous sub-class instance will be executed.

```
public abstract class Pesti {
    public abstract void ud();
    public abstract void inn();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared `p` as an instance of `Pesti`, but tried to use a method not defined in `Pesti`. When you declare your object as the abstract class you can only use the methods defined in this class. To use your `inn()` method you have to declare this method in the Pesti class as well. Alternativly you can write a class extending `Pesti` which implements the `inn()` method and declare your object as the extending class.

Answer (score 0):

`Pesti` is an `abstract` class with exactly one method (which is `abstract`): `ud()`. As such, a variable declared with the type `Pesti` can only be used to call `ud()` or any method from the class [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (`Pesti`'s implicit superclass). `p` is declared with this type, so despite actually being an instance of an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) with the method `inn()`, this method is not available in the context of having a variable of *declared* type `Pesti`.

Perhaps you intended to add the `inn()` method to `Pesti` so all instances must implement it:

```
public abstract class Pesti {
    public abstract void ud();
    public abstract void inn();
}
```

Or perhaps you don't really want to use anonymous classes at all and want to create a subclass of `Pesti` with the `inn()` method available:

```
public class PestiImpl extends Pesti {
    @Override
    public void ud() {
        System.out.println("Pestele este ud!");
    }

    public void inn() {
        System.out.println("Innoata!");
    }
}
```

(or you could have a layer of inheritance between the two; some `abstract` class extending `Pesti` with `inn()` declared as an `abstract` method, if you have other classes like this with the `inn()` method but some `Pesti`s without).

Side note: I strongly recommend using the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation where appropriate to make your code more readable and to avoid mistakes like typos when trying to override a method. You can get most IDEs to insert it automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Think you need to look at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), I don't know what do you want to do , but you can't instantiate abstract class, you can find detailed description in my link, hope it'll help you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. In addition, the user is not trying to instantiate an `abstract` class but is creating an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that is an instance of `Pesti`.